# Contacts -> New Email give Unknown Error in Smarty when Allow Mail to be sent from logged in contact's email address disabled

Tags: contacts, email, error

Running CiviCRM 5.8.2 (and earlier) under Joomla yields
Unknown error in packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1100.  Has anyone else seen this?  It seems to be due to CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/function.crmSetting.php calling civicrm_api('setting', 'getvalue', $params) in line 52, and getting an answer of false, because the parameter in question is a Boolean with value false.  A value of false is interpreted as an error.  Tweaking the record to make the value an integer (i:0 instead of b:0) solves the problem.  Maybe the civicrm_api call should return a more complex variable, with a result and an error value?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've just upgraded to 5.9.1 and the problem is still there.